# Python - getattr and concatenation

Tags: python, getattr

So in playing around with getattr in my code I discovered the following:

```
myVariable = foo.A.bar
```

works...but something like this:

```
B = "A"
myVariable = getattr(foo, B + ".bar")
```

returns an error that foo does not contain an attribute A.bar.   Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because there is no attribute `A.bar` on `foo`. Attribute `bar` is a part of the object pointed to by `A`, which is an attribute of `foo`. You need either

```
getattr(foo.A, "bar")
```

or

```
getattr(getattr(foo, 'A'), 'bar')
```

The generic code for accessing deep attributes is to split on the dot, and go until the last part is found (I'm writing from memory, not tested):

```
def getattr_deep(start, attr):
    obj = start
    for part in attr.split('.'):
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    return obj

getattr_deep(foo, 'A.bar')
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of :

```
myVariable = foo.A.bar
```

using getattr would take 2 steps.

```
aObject = getattr(foo, 'A') 
myVariable = getattr(aobject, 'bar')
```

doing it in your way `myVariable = getattr(foo, B + ".bar")
means 'myVariable = getattr(foo, "B.bar")' getAttr now lookups the string "B.bar" which obviously does not exist.