# How can I use getattr to access an attribute within an attribute?

Tags: python, getattr

What I have is a value found in:

```
value.number.odd = 7
```

`number.odd` is an input by the user, in `x`.

and so if `x='number.odd'`, I was hoping that:

```
getattr(value, x)
```

would display what `value.number.odd` would, but it doesn't. Instead I get:

```
AttributeError: missing attribute number.odd
```

EDIT:

Input x can also be something like X='number', or 'number.negative.prime'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for this ([`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in Python 3.x):

```
reduce(getattr, x.split('.'), value)
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.odd = 7
...
>>> class B:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.number = A()
...
>>> value = B()
>>> value.number.odd
7
>>> x = 'number.odd'
>>> reduce(getattr, x.split('.'), value)
7
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked beautifully

Answer (score 0):

`getattr(getattr(value, 'number'), 'odd')`

Or taken from [Python - getattr and concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778867/python-getattr-and-concatenation) by Cat Plus Plus

```
def getattr_deep(start, attr):
    obj = start
    for part in attr.split('.'):
        obj = getattr(obj, part)
    return obj

getattr_deep(foo, 'A.bar')
```

Comment: I understand that, but I thought there would be a simpler way without splitting 'number' and 'odd'. The input value x varies from a vast range of values. Some are even value.number.negative.odd

Comment: Ah, that's fair.  I don't believe there's a built-in way, but the duplicate of your question has a solution that will work for you